# Refresh current Fragment even if onCreateView is not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a Fragment whose content change day by day, the problem is that if I don't leave the Fragment and reopen it(in this way I call the onCreateView method) the Fragment doesn't update its content, so how I can update its content ?I see that if I send the app in background and I reopen it, the view isn't update, and this is a problem...

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scarsdale_home_activity, container, false);

      d=new Database(getActivity());
      String dataString=d.checkDataString();

      int start = dataString.indexOf("/");
      String dayString = dataString.substring(0,start);
      String monthString = dataString.substring(start + 1,start+3);
      String yearString = dataString.substring(start+4);
      int day = Integer.parseInt(dayString);
      int month = Integer.parseInt(monthString);
      int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString); 
      Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance(); 
      current.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      current.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);



      Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance(); 
      thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);
      thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);

      long diff = current.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis();   

      long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);   
      String strDays = new Long(days).toString();
      int intDays =Integer.parseInt(strDays);
       TextView textsca1;


        if(intDays >=0 && intDays<=6){
          d= new Database(getActivity());
          String listadietatext= d.getRow(intDays);

            textsca1=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textsca1);
            textsca1.setText(listadietatext);


        }


        return rootView;
    }
```

I tryed updating through onResume but the app crash

```
 @Override
  public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   fragTransaction.replace(R.id.container_sca,ScarsdaleHome.newIstance());
   fragTransaction.commit();

  }
```

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: I've posted my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a quick look at the Fragment Lifecycle guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle). Fragments are tightly coupled with their calling activities lifecycle. In your case, if you override the `OnResume()` method in your fragment, instead of the `onCreateView()`, then when your app goes in the background and reopened, the activitys `onResume` (and the fragments `onResume`) will both be called.

Comment: I've update my question, I try updatig in the method onResume but the app crash :(

Comment: What are you doing in your onResume method? You simply need to call your update code from onResume instead of calling it from onCreateView. Also, the activity and the fragment will each have their own onResume method. I am talking about the fragments onResume method here, not the activitys.

Comment: ok, but if I call it from onResume, then the first time I open the Fragment it doesn't contain the update content because onResume isn't called

Comment: `onResume` will be called even if you open the fragment the first time. See the flow in the link I provided in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you I have insert my code in onResume method and it works!